# Supporting byte ranges

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm developing an ASP.NET application that needs to be able to service files that include range requests. The ASP.NET MVC team has said that [they won't support this within MVC](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/272), and have recommended making use of IIS for serving static files.

Here's my issue. When users make requests, they aren't going to include any identifying information in the URL that will map directly to a file. The request might look like: http://whatever.com/Download?ID=TXlGaWxlLnhv34lk. Within MVC, I need to make a web service call to resolve that ID to a file that will ultimately be sitting on a network share. In addition, we have our own custom-built authorization mechanism that each request will have to go through before we'll service the file.

Tomasz Pęczek implemented a custom ActionResult called [RangeFileResult](http://tpeczek.blogspot.ca/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html) that seems to be reimplementing the kind of range request support that IIS does by default. I've tried using it, and it seems to work... but I feel like there should be a way to get IIS to service the static file for me.

So, ultimately, I'm wondering if it's possible to have MVC receive the request, authenticate & authorize, resolve the ID to a file path on the network share, and then fall back to IIS's StaticFile Handler to actually return the file information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly easy enough to lookup the real file location and then redirect the user to that location to download the file.  But, your real problem is authentication of the static file.  How you do this depends on your requirements (ie, Should they continue to have access even after it's downloaded?  Should each file be authorized separately?  Or access to all files?  Do you need to do additional work, like putting data in the database after a download is finished...  There's a lot of variables here.  And they all suggest different kinds of solutions.

Comment: When you say "redirect the user to that location", what do you mean? Are you envisioning that the user's browser is literally redirected to a new page? If so, that isn't what I'm looking for. The only access to the file should be through the URL with the document ID.

As far as authorization, it needs to be checked every time, regardless of whether it has been downloaded before. The authorization is on a per-file basis, not a per-directory basis. I may have to do additional work afterwards - such as writing the download request to an audit log.

Comment: @Keith - What you're suggesting then is impossible.  Once you start down the ASP.NET handler, you can no longer have IIS handle anything.  The response has to be returned via the asp.net response.  The only way to get native IIS handling is to let IIS handle the request, and if you do that, you can't let asp.net handle the request.

Comment: Thanks, Erik. Although this isn't a solution, it is an answer!